# What does this mean in CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is one of the exam questions. I have tried to google but could not find any solutions.

```
<style type="text/css">
p.i p.b, i.p b.p{color:blue}
</style>

Write an html code that will be applied with the abovementioned style.
```

What does the "." and "," operators mean in this question ?

Comment: Don't mean to be rude but you need to improve your searching skills if you couldn't find what these two are using Google search.

Comment: @Harry: He says he could not find any "solutions". Maybe he's been trying to search for an answer to the "Write an html code" part, not the "." and "," part. Good luck with that...

Comment: Whomever made that stylesheet left you with some really convoluted class names. Normally anything after the '.' would be something human readable like '.intelligent-class-name'. Perhaps you are looking at a minified stylesheet that came from a preprocessor like scss or less?

Comment: Yes - stackoverflow is not for 'i dont know how to research' questions, prior effort and research is an absolute requisite, as stated very clearly on their terms: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And since this is obviously a kinda-trick question (ridiculous class names) it is obviously NOT the first question of its type you were asked - so look at the others and whatever study you were directed to do but ignored.

Comment: @staypuftman: "This is one of the exam questions."

Comment: Bad exam question - that's just trying to confuse you. You'll never see CSS like that in the wild.

Comment: Read your text book - you know, actual study

Comment: Read about css selectors on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors , there are many more that will be useful.

Comment: Anyway, the instruction in the exam question - "Write an html code that will be applied with the abovementioned style" is not only grammatically incorrect, but downright impossible. You cannot write a `p` as a child of a `p` in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The '.' is the class and the element, and the ',' is for "this and this and so on will have this style"
p.i is a `<p>` element with the class i
p.b is a `<p>` element with the class b
i.p and b.p are italic and bold elements with a class of 'p'
they all are blue

Answer (score 1):

- In CSS classes are represented by ".".
- The "," is use in order to separate several elements that will have the same style.
- in the code that you re providing to US means that the element "p" will have the the font style as italic(cause it has a "i") and this is happening with the rest.

  Example from : [W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

  > You can also specify that only specific HTML elements should be affected by a    class.
  >   In the example below, all `<p>` elements with class="center" will be center-aligned:
  >   `p.center {`
  >   `text-align: center;`
  >   `color: red;`
  >   }